# does a power law degree distribution imply graphs are sparse?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Lets say I have a random variable with values in the space of square binary matrices from which I can sample (adjacency matrices of) graphs, and lets say that the resulting graphs have a power law degree distribution (in expectation).

Are the sampled graphs 'sparse' (the number the number of edges follows $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes)?

Similarly, can I say anything about their being 'dense' (the number of edges follows $O(n^2)$  )?

---

**Edit:** Following [@manuellafond](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85136/manuellafond)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830660/does-a-power-lore-degree-distribution-imply-graphs-are-sparse#comment1715207_830660) I see the question needs further clarification:

A power law degree distribution means that the probability $P(k)$ of a node having degree $k$ follows $P(k)=Ck^{-\gamma}$ for some $C$ and $\gamma$. If we further stipulate that $\gamma$ is the same for all graph sizes $n$, $C$ must be a function of $n$ as follows:

$C(n) = \frac{1}{\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}k^{-\gamma}}$

To be honest, I'm now not 100% sure that such a setup is at all possible, but I think so. This question is an attempt to formalise the same for social networks, which typically have power law degree distributions.

Comment: Does power law degree mean that the probability $P(k)$ that a given node is of degree $k$ is $P(k) = k^{-\gamma}$, for some constant $\gamma$ ?

Comment: You'd need a normalising constant $P(k)=Ck^{-\gamma}$, but yes, that's right. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one is answerng, here's what I get, assuming $\gamma$ is a constant.
As you say then $C = \frac{1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k^{-\gamma}} = \frac{1}{H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}}$, ${H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}}$ being the generalized Harmonic number.

Let $m$ be the number of edges of your graph $G = (V, E)$.
We'll treat $m$ as a random variable.
Denote the degree of some vertex $v \in V$ by $d(v)$.

We'd like to find out the order of $\mathbb{E}[m]$.  Using the handshake lemma,

$$\mathbb{E}[m] = \mathbb{E}[ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{v \in V} d(v)] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{v \in V} \mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \frac{1}{2} n \mathbb{E}[d(v)]$$ (for some $v \in V$).

So it all comes down to the expected degree.  For some $v \in V$, we get 
$$\mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k P(d(v) = k)= \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k C k^{-\gamma} = C \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{k^{\gamma - 1}} = \frac{H_{n-1}^{\gamma - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n-1}}$$

Now, ${H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}}$ is $O(n)$ when $\gamma = 0$, $O(\log n)$ when $\gamma = 1$ and $O(1)$ when $\gamma > 1$.

So if $\gamma = 1$, $n \frac{H_{n-1}^{\gamma - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n-1}} \in O(n \frac{n}{\log n}) = O(\frac{n^2}{\log n})$.

If $\gamma = 2$, $n \frac{H_{n-1}^{\gamma - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n-1}} \in O(n \log n)$.

If $\gamma > 2$, $n \frac{H_{n-1}^{\gamma - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n-1}} \in O(n)$.

It remains to find the order for $1 < \gamma < 2$.

Comment: good try, but $C$ or $\gamma$ (or both) must necessarily depend on $n$ in order to make $P(d(v)=k)$ into a probability distribution. If we fix $\gamma$, we end up with $\mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \frac{\sum k^{1-\gamma}}{\sum k^{-\gamma}}$, which I'm not sure what to do with...

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see your edit.  It feels like we can treat $C$ as a constant since it converges as $n$ gets larger.  Specifically, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k^{-\gamma} = \zeta(\gamma)$, the Riemann zeta function which is known to converge to some constant $c$ whenever $\gamma > 1$.
So $1/\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k^{-\gamma} \rightarrow 1/\zeta(\gamma)
$ should converge as well.  But this might need details to fill in.

Comment: Yes, $C(n)$ decreases monotonically, so in the inequality for $\mathbb{E}[d(v)]$, we can replace $C$ by its first term $C(2)=1$. I've edited the answer to accordingly. Thx (:

Comment: Your edit have been rejected it would seem...(not me !)  Anyway I still have a little doubt.  That $C$ is decreasing does make $O(n log n)$ a correct bound, but it could be less.  I mean, let's say for the sake of arguing that $C = 1/\log n$.  It's still decreasing, but it cancels out the $\log n$ in $n \log n$, and $C$ can possibly change the order of the number of edges.  I'll think about it...

Comment: For $\gamma>2$, $\mathbb{E}[d(v)]$ converges as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so is in $O(1)$, or have I missed something?? For $\gamma=2$, it's as $H_{n-1}\in O(\log n)$ (I'm guessing we can't do much better there).

Comment: And for $\gamma=1$ we end up with $(n-1)/H_{n-1} \in O(n/\log n)$ (for that we need to lower bound $H_{n-1}$ with $\log n$, but I think we can, or no?). In summary, we would now have $\mathbb{E}[m] \in O(n), O(n^2\log n), O(n^2/ \log n)$ for $\gamma >2$, $\gamma=2$ and $\gamma=1$ respectively. Thoughts?

Comment: For $\gamma = 1$, yeah.  For $\gamma = 2$, I don't know where you get the extra $n$ in $n^2 \log n$ (it's more than the max. number of edges !).  I think it should be $O(n \log n)$ under that reasoning.  But ultimately, $E[m] = \frac{H^{\gamma - 1}_{n - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}} \times n$, where $H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}$ is the generalized Harmonic function.  It all depends on the order of the ratio $\frac{H^{\gamma - 1}_{n - 1}}{H^{\gamma}_{n - 1}}$, and I can't seem to find out about it in $O$ terms.

Comment: Oops! You're right, an extra $n$ snuck in for $\gamma=2$. I was thinking of a potential lower bound $H^\gamma_n\ge M\log n$ for some $M$ so $1/H_n\in O(1/\log n)$, but now that I think more, that seems unlikely.. Do you agree for $\gamma\gt 2$?

Comment: Actually I was about to ask the question and found this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776335/determining-the-asymptotic-order-of-growth-of-the-generalized-harmonic-function.  Commenter says $H^{\gamma}$ is $o(1)$ for $\gamma > 1$, which after thought sounds right.  So all the bounds you mention in your previous comment are OK (minus the extra $^2$), and I think the case is finally closed :)

Comment: I think the $\gamma=1$ case has a problem: $H^1_n\in O(\log n)$ does *not* imply $1/H^1_n\in O(1/\log n)$. To be in $O(1/\log n)$ we need an upper bound $1/H^1_n\le M \frac{1}{\log n}$ for some $M$ (and $n\gt n_0$ for some $n_0$), and so a *lower* bound $H^1_n \ge M' \log n$ (eg: $M'=1/M$). It's not clear that we can do that.

Comment: Or maybe we can: http://mathhelpforum.com/calculus/48278-bounds-harmonic-series.html#post184347, http://rgmia.org/papers/v6n2/harmonic-ser.pdf and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620400/how-to-bound-harmonic-numbers

Comment: Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Theorem 3.2 (b) (ref'd [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56920/bounds-for-generalized-harmonic-numbers#comment142883_56920)) gives an upper bound, but not a lower one...

Comment: From what I know, actually $H^1_n \in \theta(\log n)$, which implies there exist constants $c$ and $d$ such that $c/\log(n) \leq 1/H^1_n \leq d / H^1_n$.  So both sides of the bound should be fine.  Some details here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n

Comment: Ok, so we're settled for $\gamma\ge 2$ and $\gamma = 1$. Care to add the results to the answer? (edits I make will probably not be accepted). There are probably similar results for $1\lt\gamma\lt 2$, based around an analysis of $O(1/H^\gamma_n)$ (a proof could probably be modelled on that for $\gamma=1$), but I'm satisfied with what we have already. Thx! It's been fun to put my head back in math mode for a moment :)

Comment: I edited my answer.  Yeah that was actually quite instructive.  Good thing you remained persistent on the details of this question !

Comment: Great! You should add that it's known that $1/H^1_n\in O(1/{\log n})$, as we can find a lower bound linear in $\log n$, perhaps with references.. Maybe also worth noting that finding a similar lower bound for $H^\gamma_n$ with $1\lt\gamma\lt 2$ would resolve the question for those values. Year, needless attention to detail is my downfall! Perhaps I should return to maths ;)